# Does the ICOM ID-51A's repeater search work with non-D-STAR repeaters?

Tags: repeater, ht, d-star, icom

Has anyone tested the new ICOM ID-51A Plus with regular repeaters (i.e. analog)?

I'm looking to quickly find the nearest repeater (and sign on with a PL code!) with like 1 or 2 clicks.

Is that possible with this radio?

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean by "regular repeaters"? Do you mean analog repeaters?

I haven't found a list of analog repeaters built into the ID-51A, no. But I found this site that will give you the nearest several hundred repeaters to a given location (enter your city/state and click the button). You get them in CSV format which maybe is used by Icom's programming software?

http://www.dstarinfo.com/RepeaterDownloads.aspx

But, even once you import that list I don't know if you can search by location. It may just fill the memory with those repeater frequencies and text labels.

Comment: Yeah, I just used that website.  Just downloaded the stations on a MicroSD card and then imported it in.

Answer (score 3):

Is case anyone is curious, yes...it does.

Simply push the middle button and a repeater list comes up.

It is simple to set up, as can be seen from this HOWTO guide

http://www.dstarinfo.com/Data/Sites/1/GalleryImages/FullSizeImages/id-51-beginner.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The ID-51A Plus behaves differently.  Near repeater does NOT work as documented.  I am hacking at it to try to figure it out.  Following the instructions on the above link provides nothing.  The to: is underlined and you cannot use the up down to go to the field to reset it.  Basically you are stuck in a catch where a reset is required to get you out. If someone has the true solution I would like to see it.  Also the Advanced instructions are dumbed down instructions.  The Section 6 in Advanced instructions referenced on page xii in the Basic Instructions is no good. Too bad somebody did not know what they were doing documenting the transceiver.  I am not fond of it because of the poor documentation

Answer (score 1):

The ID-51A plus advertises that it finds FM repeaters via GPS location. I have tried everything but it does not work as advertised. It has worked in only one location where I live but I have tried it while traveling with no luck.
I called Icom support, they gave me some info that did not work. Very disappointing! They also state that the ID-5100A mobile does find FM repeaters but I do not trust them. I am probably not going to buy Icom in the future

Answer (score 1):

Yes when you update your SD card change percent box of FM repeaters to a much higher number. It will locate them by zip code and give you a very complete list once imported. If you travel far just have that SD card ready plug in and download. Doesn’t affect your memory channels etc. Very easy to search and scan.